# Bootstrap jump to link inside a collapsed panel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a bootstrap panel that nests another panel inside it (Kind of like a book layout, with sections and then chapters inside each section, both levels foldable). I am trying to provide an href to the inner panel (chapter name) but if the section is currently collapsed, the browser doesn't scroll to that point.

```
<div class="accordian" id="accordion1">
 <!-- Multiple such sections -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h2 class="panel-title top-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse1">
          Section 1
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in subsection">
     <!-- Each section has multiple chapters -->
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-group" id="subaccordion1">

          <!-- Panel for chapter 1 -->
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title chapter-name" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#subaccordion1" href="#collapse1InnerOne1">
                <!-- The above link works when the panels are all expanded but not when they are collapsed. How to get it to work all the time? -->
                 Chapter 1
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1InnerOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                  Chapter 1 content
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Panel for chapter 2 -->
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title chapter-name" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#subaccordion1" href="#collapse1InnerOne2">
                 Chapter 2
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1InnerOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                  Chapter 2 content
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Panel for section 2 with chap 2&3 etc -->
```

`#collapse1InnerOne1` link works when the panels are open but not when they are collapsed. How to get it to work in both cases?
Thanks.

Comment: The Scrolling to anchor support that's native only works when the element is visible in the page. You can use `opacity:0; height:0` as  a work around.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? Where should I put those attributes?

Comment: You cannot natively do this with Bootstraps' classes. You'll need to handle your own classes. that have `opacity:1; height:auto` and `opacity:0; height:0;` and toggle them respectively.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps you..check Collapsible Group **Item #2**

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">Panel 1</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">Collapsible Group Item #2
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion21">
                                <div class="panel">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion21" href="#collapseTwoOne">View details 2.1 &raquo;
                                    </a>
                                    <div id="collapseTwoOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">Details 1</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel ">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion21" href="#collapseTwoTwo">View details 2.2 &raquo;
                                    </a>
                                    <div id="collapseTwoTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">Details 2</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseThree">Collapsible Group Item #3
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThreeOne">Collapsible Group Item #3.1
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseThreeOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                    <div class="panel-body">Panel 3.1</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThreeTwo">Collapsible Group Item #3.2
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseThreeTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                    <div class="panel-body">Panel 3.2</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: As Ohgodwhy mentioned, I don't think simple bootstrap components can achieve this (without some custom javascript). I am writing my own css/js for this but if you have some way to get bootstrap to work like desired, I would be glad to know about it :)